# How to manually force a rerender of a component in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular-template, ng2-smart-table

I am using ng Smarttable and change the datasource array via an event (the change is an id change of a value inside the array). The problem is that angular doesnt detect the changes and nothing happens UNTIL i hover over the page or click somewhere.

So the changes are correctly applied behind the scenes and angular "sees" these changes once i click somewhere.

So i could just manually click alot of times to see the chaning property, but this is not desired.

I tried:

1. using ChangeDetectorRef inside the function where i change the array (markAsChanged & DetectChange)
2. manually making a click event once the array is changed
3. Using Immutability (*this.data= [...this.data];*)

Is it possible to have something like this?

```
this.renderer.refresh();
```

or use just a functionality of ng smartable?

EDIT: it looks like the problem was on my side. When you "refresh" the smarttable,you get a promise which only executes once the loading is finished.

I didnt used the promise. Putting the normal DetectChange() inside the promise made it work

Comment: Have you tried immutability ? When you change the datasource for example you have a `data` array try writing this line in your event listener: `this.data = [...this.data]`.

Comment: Yes, its not working

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your code here or on Stackblitz and tell us the current and desired behaviors?

Comment: unfortunately i dont think this is possible since its code from work

Comment: Have you tried the ng2-smarttable refresh method: https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/issues/109# or look at their documentation

Comment: yes, but the problem was on my side. Look at the edit for the solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can manually re-render using application ref.

Inject ApplicationRef to your component.

```
constructor(appRef: ApplicationRef) {}
```

Then call tick method whenever you want to re-render

```
appRef.tick();
```

Comment: For an library specific solution, check on this thread. https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/issues/718

Comment: @Loading great. But for the question you asked, how to do a manual re-rendering, this is the answer.

Comment: This is brilliant! Nice and short. Thanks a lot!